# Classes *Factory from generated/ directory isn't use and look for them in vendor directory. Magento2.3

Tags: magento2.3, factory

I'm using `Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory` in my module and in unit tests.
Unit tests doesn't pass because `CategoryFactory` doesn't exists.
Class `CategoryFactory` exists in `generated` directory and doesn't exists in `vendor`. Magento 2 in first order check `generated` directory and if there is no searched class, then search inside `vendor` directory.
Directory `generated` was deleted many times and now have rights 777. I clean it many times and nothings help. During compile (`setup:di:compile`), Magento 2 creates needed files but some files doesn't use.
Earlier this code works and nothings change inside code, only programming environment. I'm using vagrant and CentOs on VirtualBox.
The same problem is with other *Factory classes.
Do You have any idea, what is the problem?

Comment: try to delete the **generated** folder then run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` which will generate all necessary classes

Comment: I wrote that i did it many times. CategoryFactory exists inside generated but Magento don't use it and returns error.

Comment: It would help if you shared the exact error you are getting.

Comment: OK then I'm guessing not sure.. you can check the permission of the specific CategoryFactory file maybe the file don't have the permission

Comment: This file have 644 - file was created by magento during `setup:di:compile`

Comment: Commands `chmod 0777 generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/CategoryFactory.php` and `sudo chown vagrant:nginx -R generated/` change nothing

Comment: give the permission like `sudo chmod -R 777 generated`

Comment: Is it possible that problem is inside local (PhpStorm)?

Comment: I even use commands `sudo chcon -R --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t generated/ var/ pub/media/ pub/static/ app/etc/` and `sudo chmod -R 777 generated/ var/ pub/media/ pub/static/ app/etc/` but this change nothing